How change button call become whatsapp on flutter?
I making coding from template flutter
But i cant understand how to change call button become whatsapp button.
This is my code :
Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: ActionButtonWidget(
                                        buttonName: getTranslatedValue(
                                            context, "call_to_customer"),
                                        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                                            bottom: 10, end: 5),
                                        voidCallback: () {
                                          launchUrlAction(
                                              "tel://${order.userMobile}");
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: ActionButtonWidget(
                                        buttonName: getTranslatedValue(
                                            context, "get_customer_direction"),
                                        padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                                            bottom: 10, start: 5),
                                        voidCallback: () {
                                          launchUrlAction(
                                              "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=${order.customerLatitude},${order.customerLongitude}");
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),

Help me please. Thank you.

Provide ActionButtonWidget code and image that you want to create.

Oh i did it.. just call function url
im solve it by myself
child: ActionButtonWidget(
    buttonName: getTranslatedValue(
                                        context, "call_to_customer"),
                                    padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                                        bottom: 10, end: 5),
                                    voidCallback: () {
                                      launchUrlAction(
                                       "https://wa.me/${order.userMobile}?text=Hello.");
                                    },
                                  ),

